# CORS issue trying to use Github Auth

Tags: json, reactjs, github

I tried to create a component in my newly react profile and trying to use the Github authentication but this is the error I get at the console: Any help please
Error: "Access to fetch at 'https://api.github.com/users/******' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authoriztion is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
Profile.js:14 TypeError: Failed to fetch"

```
import React, {
    Component
}
from 'react';
class Profile extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        let header = new Headers({
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authoriztion": "token *******"
        });
        fetch('https://api.github.com/users/*******', {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: header
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                console.log(json)
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));

    }

    render() {

        return (

            The Profile goes here

        );
    }
}
export default Profile;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your question's title, formatting and unnecessary code won't help anyone to resolve the problem. Please make the edits accordingly!

Comment: I would thoroughly recommend reading what you post, before you post it - for instance you may not wish to post your tokens are your username to SO (They've been removed)

Answer (score 0):

change :

```
let header = new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json","Authoriztion":"token 719bd0dc90b6f6d6cc03a3f61d43f258f3fdec2a"});
```

to

```
let header = new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json","Authorization":"token 719bd0dc90b6f6d6cc03a3f61d43f258f3fdec2a"});
```

Or just change `Authoriztion` to `Authorization`